MC pricing of varswap and volswap in Variance-Gamma model
I am trying to price a discretely monitored (daily) varswap and volswap in the variance gamma model (see Madan, Carr and Chang paper for more details about VG model).
I expect the values to be close to exact continuously monitored values, which for the parameters I use should be varswap = 12.14% and volswap = 11.64%.
The MC simulation indeed gives varswap value close to exact value, but the volswap is consistently underestimated at 11.06%. Granted I'm not using control variates, but the difference is too large. Something is not right but I can't figure out what it is.
In the VG model I define a varswap as
$$
\sqrt{E \left[ \frac1T \sum_i ( \log S_{i+1}/S_i )^2 \right]}
$$
and the volswap as
$$
E \left[\sqrt{ \frac1T \sum_i ( \log S_{i+1}/S_i )^2 }\right]
$$
If anybody sees the error I'd be happy to hear! The code below is Octave (free Matlab) code.
tic

pkg load statistics;
output_precision(7);

S0 = 1;  %Hence ln S0 = 0
r = 0; q = 0;
T = 0.5;

sigma = 0.1214;
nu = 0.1686;
theta = -0.5*sigma^2; 

nsteps = 180; nsims = 500000;

dt = T/nsteps;

a = dt/nu; 
b = nu;

vgmat = gamrnd(a,b,nsteps,nsims);
smat = randn(nsteps,nsims);

omega = (1/nu)*log(1-theta*nu-0.5*sigma^2*nu)
mat = ((r- q + omega)*dt + theta*vgmat + sigma*sqrt(vgmat).*smat).^2;

varsw = sqrt(mean((1/T)*sum(mat(:,:))))
volsw = mean(sqrt((1/T)*sum(mat(:,:))))

toc

